# suitable datastructure to store the parsed data from webservice

Tags: iphone

I am developing an iphone app that utilizes webservice. Which is the most suitable datastructure that can be used to store the data as the XML obtained from the webservice is parsed ...?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question well, there's no single datastructure that you can use (it highly depends on the shape of xml though). As a matter of fact that's the beauty of Object Oriented Programming, where you can create your own classes in order to store custom data obtained for example from XML.